# iOS9 SKPaymentQueue related issue - transaction unexpectedly terminated when app returns to foreground

Tags: ios, download, in-app-purchase, ios9, storekit

## Transaction Suddenly /Unexpectedly/ Removed from SKPaymentQueue - any ideas why?

### Intro

We experience a strange behaviour of SKPaymentQueue under iOS-9 and iOS-9.0.1. We suspect that this is an iOS issue. 
This example is a minimal app-frame that demonstrates the SKPaymentQueue related issue. Download the example [here](https://github.com/IgorTavcar/TransactionSuddenlyRemoved).

### Facts

- Issue appears in sandbox environment (iOS 9.0.1).
- Issue appears in TestFlight environment (iOS 9.0.1).
- Never tested in production environemt.
- Never tested on iOS 9.1 /beta/.
- Issue never appears on iOS 8.4.1.

### App

This app requires one non-consumable IAP product with content hosted on Apple. 
App has only one button that starts the transaction/download process.

### Issue

Download process is unexpectedly terminated when app is moved from the foreground to the background and then back to the foreground.

To reproduce the issue ...

1. Adapt this project to your dev. environment (set NON_CONSUMABLE_PRODUCT_WITH_HOSTED_CONTENT to your IAP product-id).

   - Create a test app (iTunes Connect).
   - Host a non-consumable IAP product (Application Loader).
2. Press the button "Get Product".
3. Wait until downloading starts.
4. Press Home button to resign the app.
5. (Re)Activate the app (touch the app icon).
6. SKPaymentQueue will eventually send one or two download update events.
7. !! SKPaymentQueue will send the paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, removedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])` message to the observer.
8. !! Downloading is now terminated (no events).

### Known Workarounds

- Keep the app in the foreground while downloading.
- Don't activate the app until the downloading is completed (at the system level), then activate the app.

Comment: Issue reported to apple with id 22912989.

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same behavior, very frustrating.  Did you manage to find any solution beyond the above workarounds?  Starting a bounty as well.

Comment: Nope. Our app is in the queue for public release now. We tried many things to kill this bug... we can't wait any longer. So, next testers are our users themselves. :(

Comment: Good news, it suddenly started working for us today.  We made no changes - seems to be a resolved glitch on Apple's side.  You seeing the same thing?

Comment: I've just tested that. It is true -  problem disappeared :) - without any changes at our side. But !! we've spent at least 15 programer-hours resolving something that couldn't be resolved - for what exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding the background keys for your app?

You can set them in the info.plist or in capabilities...

1. info.plist way - Add "fetch" for "UIBackgroundModes"
2. Go to Capabilities > Background Modes toggle this on. And select the fetch field.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22

Answer (score 0):

Good news, anomaly suddenly disappeared, and as consequence - this question is closed /without any obvious conclusion/. 
[Github code](https://github.com/IgorTavcar/TransactionSuddenlyRemoved) is a side product of this question and can be used as a minimalistic example with **non-consumable IAP** and **content hosted by Apple**.